# Passing a value into an Xpath expression

Tags: c#, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am currently writing a test against an e-commerce website. When a user runs a search for a particular product a list of items are being returned. What I am hoping to do is pass a particular value (e.g. the number 2) into my test scenario, at which point can be passed into my XPath expression (nth-child), enabling the item to be selected.

The XPath is incorrect and not sure how to fix it. Would appreciate if someone could help.

```
   [Then(@"I select item '(.*)' from the search results")]
    public static void WaitAndSelectAnItem(int item)
    {
        {
            Driver.Instance.FindElements(By.CssSelector("#productGrid"));
            var itemToSelect = Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.XPath(string.Format("//@class='itemContainer:nth-child({0})'", item)));
            itemToSelect.Click();
        }
    }
```

Result Message: The given selector //@class='itemContainer:nth-child(3)' is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:
InvalidSelectorError: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //@class='itemContainer:nth-child(3)' because of the following error:
TypeError: The expression cannot be converted to return the specified type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nth-child` is not part of the XPath language and is actually a CSS selector pseudo-class.

Instead, you've probably meant:

```
(//*[@class='itemContainer'])[{0}]
```

Note that indexing in XPath starts with `1` - make sure you are actually getting the correct item.

---

Alternatively, you can use `findElements()` to find all "itemContainers" and then get the desired one by index. Note that it is 0-indexed here:

```
Driver.Instance.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@class='itemContainer']"))[item]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the "item container" is a DIV tag, if not div replace div by the right tag, * will work as well but there may be chances that you get more elements which you don't want.

Try this:

```
(//div[@class='itemContainer'])[1]
```

Replace 1 by your item indices.